# Why the above statement is not being executed first

Tags: ios, objective-c, master-detail

i have used master-detail view in my application.
[image]

when videos row is selected in master view , the videos method is called and it is as shown above, in the videos method i am writing code to dismiss the popover and calling a method fetchvideosfromurl: , but during execution the method fetchvideosfromurl is being executed first and after that the popover dismisses, but i want the popover to be dismissed before the method is called, how to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following:

-(void)videos
{
[popover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
[self performSelector(loadUrl) withobject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

}

-()loadUrl
{
  //code in the following Image
}

[image]

hope this will help you.

Comment: the problem is solved, but why did the execution is not in the order of the instructions given.